# generating array automatically

Tags: php, arrays, frameworks, drop-down-menu, yii

I want to create a dropdown list in Yii framework and I have the problem generating it automatically

so there is what I have now:

```
function getYear($value1 = 1900, $value2 = 2008)
{
    $data = array();

    for ($i=value1; $i++; $i<=value2){
        array_push($data,(string)$i);
    }

    return data();
}

<?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'yy', getYear()); ?>
```

it should look like this:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'field_name', array(1=>'test1', 2=>'test2'));?>
```

but my code doesn't work so please help me

Comment: I hope that's not for a birthdate. If it is: Please do not hardcode years. In 15 years someone born in 2008 might very well use your site and chances are good that nobody remembers updating that hardcoded year. But of course chances are also good that the site will not exist anymore or has been rewritten at least once in 15 years.

Comment: I am the owner of this site so I will update it every year. I need to solve this problem, so please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need a separate function - just use the PHP range() function as Joe showed.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'field_name', range(1900,2008);?>
```

As ThiefMaster said - best not to hardcode these values, so perhaps:

```
<?php 
$thisyear = date("Y");
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'field_name', range($thisyear-100,$thisyear);
?>
```

This is assuming your $form is an object of class CActiveForm

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the YII framework but it looks like your function has some major syntactical issues. First, the parameters in your `for()` loop are in the wrong order. Additionally, you are missing `$` in front of the `$value1` and `$value2` variables so they are being interpreted as empty constants.

If you want to return an array populated with sequential years you may want to check out the native `range()` function.  Like this:

```
function getYear($value1 = 1900, $value2 = 2008) {
    return range($value1, $value2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your function in a class and define it a static function so that you can use it in other places also. And then call the function statically.

```
class example{
  public static function getYear($value1 = 1900, $value2 = 2008)
  {
     $data = array();

     for ($i=value1; $i++; $i<=value2){
         array_push($data,(string)$i);
     }

     return data();
  }
}

<?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'yy', example::getYear()); ?>
```